# How to detect red pixels in a Bitmap

Tags: android, camera, pixel

Does getPixels() in android read the pixels up-down left-right, or left-right up-down. Basically does it read by rows, or columns. If I wanted to tell where in a picture are the red values higher, can I do this(I assumed it read by columns).

```
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        int[] pixels = new int[thumbnail.getHeight()*thumbnail.getWidth()];

        thumbnail.getPixels( pixels, 0, thumbnail.getWidth(), 0, 0, thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight());
        Colered[] color = new Colered[pixels.length];
        int length = pixels.length;
        int width = thumbnail.getWidth();
        int height = thumbnail.getHeight();
        for(int i=0; i<pixels.length;i++){
            color[i] = new Colered(getRed(pixels[i]),getBlue(pixels[i]),getGreen(pixels[i]));
            System.out.print(color[i].red + " ");
        }
        int indice=-1;
        int greatest = -1;
        for(int i=0;i<length-1;i++){
            if(color[i].red> greatest){
                greatest = color[i].red;
                indice = i;
            }


        } 

       public static int getRed(int color){
    return (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
   }
```

Comment: I wrote a program in c# similar to what you are trying to do, one thing I noticed is that red is rarely ever red in a picture, you will have to give it a range of possible reds, perhaps using RGB where R is greater than X and G and B is less than Y for example.

Comment: convert the bitmap to pixels array then loop through it and find the red pixel if any!

Comment: `Does getPixels() in android read the pixels up-down left-right, or left-right up-down. Basically does it read by rows, or columns` **NO**. It reads the `specific x,y coordinate`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks for the "reddest" pixel, the pixel with the highest red value. I don't think that's actually what you need, but correct me if I'm wrong.

You're also over complicating things. Let's start with a `Bitmap` and two loops:

```
int redThreshold = 200; // adjust this to your needs
List<int[]> redPixels = new ArrayList<>(); // redPixels.get(int)[0] = x, redPixels.get(int)[1] = y
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
for(int x = 0; x  < thumbnail.getWidth(); x++) // x is row
    for(int y = 0; y < thumbnail.getHeight(); y++) // y is col
        if(Color.red(thumbnail.getPixel(x, y)) > redThreshold) {
            redPixels.add(new int[]{x, y});
            System.out.println(String.format("Pixel at (%d, %d) has a red value exceeding our threshold of %d!", x, y, redThreshold);
        }
```

As @Eliseo hints at in his comment, depending on your actual needs, you may need to check that the other two colors are below a certain threshold as well, as this will pick up colors such as white (r=255,g=255,b=255 is white!).

So, how do we look for visual reds? Something you and I would look at and agree is just "red". Well, let's make sure our red value has an appropriate ratio to the greater of either green or blue; and that blue and green are within a threshold of eachother, or else we'll catch pink and orange. Something like this:

```
int thresholdRatio = 2;
int threshold = 15;
List<int[]> redPixels = new ArrayList<>();
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
for(int x = 0; x < thumbnail.getWidth(); x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < thumbnail.getHeight(); y++) {
        Color color = thumbnail.getPixel(x, y);
        int r = Color.red(color);
        int g = Color.green(color);
        int b = Color.blue(color);
        if((r > (Math.max(g, b) * thresholdRatio)) && (Math.abs(g - b) < threshold)) {
            redPixels.add(new int[]{x, y});
            System.out.println(String.format("Pixel at (%d, %d) has a red value more than %d times the max(green, blue) value, and the green and blue value are also within %d points!", x, y, thresholdRatio, threshold);
       }
    }
```

This will catch very light and very dark shades of red. Add a ceiling and floor threshold, if you need to catch very specific shades of red.

Want to visualize which pixels are caught? We can if the bitmap is mutable.

```
Random rand = new Random();
Color getRandomColor() {
    int[] rgb = new int[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
        rgb[i] = rand.nextInt(256);
    }
    return Color.rgb(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
}

boolean transformRedPixels(Bitmap bm, List<int[]> redPixels) {
    for(int[] coords : redPixels) {
        bm.setPixel(coords[0], coords[1], getRandomColor()); // This will set each pixel caught to a new random color
    }
    return bm.isMutable();
}
```

Let me know if this suits your needs. Happy coding :)