# Detecting if the Bitmap I have is black and white or a color image

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I have an image URI and I am getting the `Bitmap` from that URI using the code below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
       bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I want to check if the `Bitmap` is a black and white or a color image.

(There will either be a black/white image or a colored one)

How can I do this?
I am using Java on Android.

Comment: It might help to start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204488/how-to-detect-red-pixels-in-a-bitmap

Comment: Do you actually mean "black and white" (i.e. each pixel is either black or white and there's nothing else)?  Or do you mean greyscale (i.e. each pixel has equal red, green and blue components)?

Comment: Yes I guess I mean to say greyscale. 
I need to check this for the purpose of knowing if the image is a photocopy or a colored image.

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension function in kotlin, you can use this or make a similar function in java with same logic

```
fun Bitmap.isColored(): Boolean{
for (x in 0 until this.width){
    for (y in 0 until this.height){
        val color = this.getColor(x,y)
        val blue = color.blue()
        val red = color.red()
        val green = color.green()

        if(blue!=red || blue!=green || red!=green){
            return true
        }
    }
}

return false
}
```

to use an extension function just call `isColored = yourBitmap.isColored()`

Edit: java function

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
boolean isColored(Bitmap bitmap){
    for (int x = 0; x< bitmap.getWidth(); x++){
        for (int y = 0 ;y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++){
            Color color = bitmap.getColor(x,y);
            float blue = color.blue();
            float red = color.red();
            float green = color.green();

            Log.d( "blue: " , Float.toString(blue));
            Log.d( "red: " , Float.toString(red));
            Log.d( "green: " , Float.toString(green));


            if(blue!=red || blue!=green || red!=green){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Edit 2: Main activity in java showing its use

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    InputStream ins= getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(
                    "image",
                    "raw", getPackageName()
            )
    );

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins);

    Log.d( "isColored: ", "" + isColored(bitmap));
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
boolean isColored(Bitmap bitmap){
    for (int x = 0; x< bitmap.getWidth(); x++){
        for (int y = 0 ;y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++){
            Color color = bitmap.getColor(x,y);
            float blue = color.blue();
            float red = color.red();
            float green = color.green();

            Log.d( "blue: " , Float.toString(blue));
            Log.d( "red: " , Float.toString(red));
            Log.d( "green: " , Float.toString(green));


            if(blue!=red || blue!=green || red!=green){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you but can you please post the java implementation too so that I could be clear on using certain methods and datatypes.

Comment: Added java code.

Comment: I have tried the above method and checked the bitmap config and its ARGB_8888.
Also even if the image is black and white the values for blue, green and red are different so it returns true even if the image is black and white so its not working.

Comment: Can you please give a workaround for this function?

Comment: Can you share the image that you are testing for this>

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VEKy9AdlBUJq6tESSrhziON6BeccgsRC/view?usp=sharing

Above is the google drive link for the image. This is a sample image because cannot share real image as it is a identification document of a client.

Comment: Pls give me access to this file

Comment: I have given access just now please check

Comment: Have you tried the same image for testing?

Comment: Yes I have tried it

Comment: OK let me check with it

Comment: Have modified the code as well because there were errors in the function you provided my code is in the next comment.

Comment: `    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static boolean isColored(Bitmap bitmap) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
                int green = Color.green(pixel);
                int red = Color.red(pixel);
                if (blue != red || blue != green || red != green) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

Comment: Hey! I tried with the same image and same code, for me it says, false, i.e the image is not colored

Comment: Sorry for me its returning true even if the image is black and white. And returning true if its colored i.e. in both cases it returns true. The value of float blue, float green and float red never are never same even if its a black and white image :(

Comment: Can you try Float.compare(blue,red)!=0 ||  Float.compare(blue,green)!=0 || Float.compare(green,red)!=0 condition in if statement

Comment: If possible can you please share your working code with me ? Like how are you getting you bitmap from image and further processing. Because I tried multiple times and I dont get 0 values for blue, red and green even if its a black and white image. :)

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check

Comment: Will check. Also did you take the image from your machines screen or did you print it out and checked?

Comment: I took the digital image. no printout or from camera because taking image from camera will not work in this manner. For that you will need to apply some ML model and wont be possible by native android component because camera will surely capture other lights

Comment: Okay. In my use case the image gets captured through camera and then is passed to check if its colored or not, maybe that is the reason why its not working for me.

Comment: Then I dont think it is possible on device with native methods.